# I bought the Super Smash Bros for 3DS and Wii U Lucas DLC on my 3DS, but it didn't appear on my Wii U

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, wii-u, super-smash-bros-4

I bought Super Smash Bros for 3DS and wanted a DLC, so I bought Lucas for 3DS and Wii U, but Lucas doesn't appear on my Wii U. I don't know how to link my accounts together. How do I link them together?

Comment: Were you given a download code when you got it on your 3DS? If so, did you try entering the code on your Wii U?

Answer (score 8):

You were given a download code for the Wii U version when you bought the 3DS DLC. [This page details how to get that download code and then use it on the Wii U](http://www.smashbros.com/us/dlc/how-to-purchase.html):

> **1. The Nintendo eShop on Nintendo 3DS**
>
> The download code for the Wii U content included in the "3DS & Wii U" option will be listed on the Receipt. You can view the Receipt by going to the Nintendo 3DS Nintendo eShop and selecting Menu → Settings / Other → Account Activity → View Receipt.
>
> **2. Wii U Nintendo eShop**
>
> Enter the 16-digit code listed on the Receipt into the Wii U Nintendo eShop, and the download for the DLC will begin. Once finished, the purchased DLC will be available on Super Smash Bros. for Wii U.

The images indicate how to do this:

- Open the eShop from the Wii U Menu (or Home Menu).
- At the top of the eShop's front page, tap "Enter Download Code".
- Enter the 16-digit code from the aforementioned 3DS receipt.
- Confirm the content is correct, and tap "Download".
- Confirm you have sufficient space on the Wii U to download the content.
- Wait for the download to be commence.

After the download finishes:

> Please close the Super Smash Bros. for Wii U software after purchasing DLC. The installation of the content will complete on the Wii U menu. You may then restart the software, and the DLC will be available.